# mvc best practice for common code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application.  The following code is being used in multiple places within a controller and in multiple controllers.  I would like to have this code in one place and call it from each location.  What's the best way to do that in MVC?

The code below gets a row from the database and creates ViewData that can be read from the view.  With webforms, I would create a public sub within a class and pass the year and month values.  Is there a way this code could become part of the model?

```
var monthlyexpenseincome = (from vu_monthlyresult in dbBudget.vu_MonthlyResults
                            where vu_monthlyresult.Month == defaultmonth && vu_monthlyresult.Year == defaultyear
                            select vu_monthlyresult).Single();

var yearlyexpenseincome =  (from vu_yearlyresult in dbBudget.vu_YearlyResults
                            where vu_yearlyresult.Year == defaultyear
                            select vu_yearlyresult).Single();

ViewData["MonthlyExpenses"] = monthlyexpenseincome.Expenses;
ViewData["MonthlyIncome"] = monthlyexpenseincome.Income;
ViewData["MonthlyProfit"] = monthlyexpenseincome.Income - monthlyexpenseincome.Expenses;
```

Comment: Look into the Facade pattern to handle your data queries.

Comment: Check Repository Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Generally, If you have common code across multiple controllers, you can create another class which inherits from Controller and keep your methods there and let your indidual Controlellers inherit this new class

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   protected string GetThatInfo()
   {
      //do your magic logic and return some thing useful
      return "This is demo return.Will be replaced";
   }
}
```

And now you can inherit from this for your other controllers

```
public class UserController: BaseController 
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return VieW();
  } 
}
```

**But In your case, The data you are taking is something specific to your Domain data**. so i would suggest you to move it to a different class ( like a new Service / Business Layer)

```
public static class ProfitAnalysis
{
  public static decimal GetTotalExpense()
  {
     //do your code and return total
  }

}
```

And you can call it from wherever you wanted like

```
decimal totalExp=ProfitAnalysis.GetTotalExpense();
```

**And You will soon realize, Having so much `ViewData` usage is making your code difficult to read and Maintain. Do not wait for that day. Switch to strongly typed classes to pass data.**

Answer (score 0):

You should place your queries in a "business layer", which is just a class that you call to do the business logic.  Then you can reuse it in any place you like, just instantiate the business class and use it.  You could also make the methods static if they don't require state, then you wouldn't have to even instantiate it.

For example:

```
var expenseService = new expenseService();

ViewData["MonthlyExpenses"] = expenseService.GetMonthlyExpenses();
```